# c++ virtual inheritance with inherited constructor g++ compiler error

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I'm compiling the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

struct stack_error : public virtual std::logic_error {
 using std::logic_error::logic_error;
 //explicit stack_error(std::string const& what_arg) :  std::logic_error(what_arg) {}
};

struct stack_empty_error : public stack_error {
  explicit stack_empty_error(std::string const& what_arg) :  std::logic_error(what_arg), stack_error(what_arg) {}
};

struct stack_full_error : public stack_error {
  explicit stack_full_error(std::string const& what_arg) : std::logic_error(what_arg), stack_error(what_arg) {}
};

int main() {
  stack_full_error e(std::string("WOW"));
  std::cout << "ok" << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

with gcc 6.3 and I don't understand why it gives me the following error
(I think that the using std::error_logic... injects its 2 constructor in stack_error but if I use the commented out code everything is fine.

g++ -std=c++1z -Wall -Wextra -pedantic vbase.cpp -o vbase

(note clang++ compile it without error 
clang++ -std=c++1z -Wall -Wextra -pedantic vbase.cpp -o vbase)

```
vbase.cpp: In constructor 'stack_empty_error::stack_empty_error(const string&)':
vbase.cpp:13:111: error: use of deleted function 'stack_error::stack_error(const string&)'
explicit stack_empty_error(std::string const& what_arg) : std::logic_error(what_arg), stack_error(what_arg) {}
                                                                                                               ^
vbase.cpp:6:27: note: 'stack_error::stack_error(const string&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
using std::logic_error::logic_error;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
vbase.cpp:6:27: error: no matching function for call to 'std::logic_error::logic_error()'
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.3.0/system_error:41:0,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/ios_base.h:46,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.3.0/ios:42,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.3.0/ostream:38,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:39,
                 from vbase.cpp:1:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.3.0/stdexcept:128:5: note: candidate: std::logic_error::logic_error(const std::logic_error&)
logic_error(const logic_error&) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT;
^~~~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.3.0/stdexcept:128:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.3.0/stdexcept:124:5: note: candidate: std::logic_error::logic_error(const char*)
logic_error(const char*) _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE;
^~~~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.3.0/stdexcept:124:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.3.0/stdexcept:120:5: note: candidate: std::logic_error::logic_error(const string&)
logic_error(const string& __arg) _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE;
^~~~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.3.0/stdexcept:120:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
vbase.cpp: In constructor 'stack_full_error::stack_full_error(const string&)':
vbase.cpp:19:110: error: use of deleted function 'stack_error::stack_error(const string&)'
explicit stack_full_error(std::string const& what_arg) : std::logic_error(what_arg), stack_error(what_arg) {}
```

Comment: It does not make sense to use virtual inheritance here.. Either you want to catch a specific error and use the appropriate derived class or want to catch a more general error and catch the base class. This is a poor design.

Comment: It's example of behaviour i don't understand isn't production code. You can use struct a, struct b and struct c if you prefer.

Comment: A compiler bug, perhaps? It also compiles with a GCC 7 snapshot I tried, and with VC 2017.

Comment: Yes possible, or different interpretation of standard? I was very surprised of the fact gcc don't compile and clang does